# Setting the data type of columns from a CSV file of just headers

Tags: r, dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

tbl1 <- tibble(data.frame(
  a = c(1,2),
  b = c(3,4)
))

tbl2 <- c('a','b','c','d') %>% purrr::map_dfc(
  setNames, object = list(numeric()))
```

I want to add all the rows of `tbl1` to `tbl2`, with columns that are in `tbl2` and not `tbl1` as `NA`. So the tbl would look like this:

```
a b c  d
1 3 NA NA
2 4 NA NA
```

How do I do this without having to manually list columns `c` and `d`?

Comment: Maybe `bind_rows(tbl1,tbl2) %>% mutate(across(everything(),~as.character(.)))` loading `tidyverse` first!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `dplyr::bind_rows` is useful for this.

```
> bind_rows(tbl1, tbl2)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
      a     b     c     d
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     3    NA    NA
2     2     4    NA    NA
```

2. You can define a `tbl_df` object directly with `tibble()`. You do not need to do `tibble(data.frame(<values>))`. A `tbl_df` is basically just a data.frame with a fancy print method and some (external) grouping support.
3. Similarly, you can define an empty tbl directly: `tibble(a = numeric(), b = numeric(), c = numeric(), d = numeric())`

Comment: you mean `bind_rows`?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `rbindlist`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(tbl1, tbl2))
```